# Media query for one fixed resolution

Tags: css

I need to fix responsiveness of website on this fixed-width `width:360px;`. But I can't figure out the media query to use.

Will it be `@media only screen and (width:360px)` or will this will work 
`@media all and (max-width: 362px) and (min-width:361px)`?

Answer (score 5):

yes you can use `@media only screen and (width:360px){}` it will work