# CSS media query for 5:4 desktop

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Is it possible to create a media query for 5:4 desktops (1280x1024)?

I'm trying with this code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1281px) and (min-height: 1023px) {

}
```

..but it still not working

Comment: If your desktop is `1280px` wide, then the max-width wouldn't be `1281px`, would it?

Comment: So my max-width should be 1280px?
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-height: 1024px) {
}
Doesn't work too

Comment: possible duplicate of [Media query for one fixed resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666321/media-query-for-one-fixed-resolution)

Comment: If i test the page on screenfly on 1280x1024 resolution It works.. But if I open the page on the desktop with the same resolution It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not working, because your browser does not have 1280x1024px on desktop with that resolution (it is smaller - something like 1260x980px because of scrollbar etc.)

Comment: 'screen' rule applies on the device's size and not the window's size, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, you can use @media screen and (max-DEVICE-width: 1280px) for that. http://www.menucool.com/3613/max-device-width-vs-max-width-Which-one-should-I-use